# How to convert ppt/pptx to json in java

Tags: java, powerpoint, ms-office

Needed:

1. All components(including text/shape/table/image/video);
2. Precise properties of components,like position/color/backgroundcColor/size/rotate/animation/super link/font style etc.

We have tried Aspose.slide and Apache POI, but got less precise attributes, is there any other java plugin can do it?

Comment: Why using JSON for it?

Comment: We need show and edit ppt file in browser, and we need to implement the edited page ourselves, is there any other data format can fulfill this requirement ？  @fluffy

Comment: I want to convert  ppt to json ,and convert json to editable html code.

Comment: PPT/PPTX are complex formats and are presentation-serialized already. Why not just send PPTX (optionally unpacked), and parse XML on the client side so that it won't be relied on a possible data loss while converting from XML to JSON (both formats are not really mutually convertible)? Or even use a ready-to-use libraries that deal with PPT/PPTX? Using JSON would probably only make sense if you're going to have reduced support for presenting PPT/PPTX files in your web app.

Comment: I‘m not sure if we can use broswer to read  xml file in PPT/PPTX , can you say more about it? And I didn't find a good library to deal with PPT/PPTX, I tried to use nodejs to deal with PPT/PPTX, but get a very complex data file more 50kb.

Comment: I've googled a few in-browser solutions. Browser APIs are not JSON-only, those solutions can work (I don't know whether they are complete enough, though). I'm trying to point out that converting _something_ to an intermediate format must be taken carefully because of potential data loss at this stage. Note that complex data will also be complex in any format, regardless XML or JSON, so there is no need to reinvent the wheel. Use custom representation only either your app needs lightweight support, or you're going to match the source format very precisely (you've got to make a decision anyway).

Comment: Also, from a design perspective, you would probably not need anything dynamic at back-end if your back-end and the application can serve static presentation files (therefore no on-fly conversion). Making them editable at the client side would be more complex to do, and this is where JSON _may_ come into game: your client could send the modification steps (whatever user does), and the back-end could translate those commands to the PPT/PPTX files stored at back-end.

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot of blind spots from your answer. Maybe edit file in back-end is a better way.